# Extend window size according to window caption/label in qooxdoo

Tags: arrays, user-interface, properties, frameworks, qooxdoo

I have a window with a caption and two buttons. The window caption is longer than two buttons and I got three dots in the window caption. Is there some way to fix it I mean get rid of dots and see the full caption? Maybe try other ways for example use label in window body but I am afraid of the result will be the same.

```
var win = new qx.ui.window.Window("First Window");
win.setLayout(new qx.ui.layout.HBox());
win.setShowMinimize(false);

var yesBtn = new qx.ui.form.Button("Yes");
var noBtn = new qx.ui.form.Button("No");
win.add(yesBtn);
win.add(noBtn);

this.getRoot().add(win, {left:20, top:20});
win.open();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example showing the way to do it dynamically. You can copy/paste this into the playground at https://qooxdoo.org/qxl.playground/#%7B%22code%22%3A%22%22%7D

```
function onAppear()
{
  let styles;
  let resolvedFont;
  let content;
  let min;
  let captionWidget = this.getChildControl("title");
  let font = captionWidget.getFont();

  // Extra space needed to account for buttons, e.g., maximize, close.
  // This could be made dynamic using `getShowMaximize()`, etc.
  // Here, assigned a fixed value that works with maximize and close buttons
  let excess = 70;

  if (font)
  {
    resolvedFont = qx.theme.manager.Font.getInstance().resolve(font);
    styles = resolvedFont.getStyles();
  }
  else
  {
    styles = qx.bom.getDefaultStyles();
  }

  content = this.getCaption() || "A";
  min = qx.bom.Label.getTextSize(content, styles);
  this.setMinWidth(min.width + excess);
}

function addWindow(root, caption, top)
{
  var win = new qx.ui.window.Window(caption);

  win.setLayout(new qx.ui.layout.HBox());
  win.setShowMinimize(false);

  var yesBtn = new qx.ui.form.Button("Yes");
  var noBtn = new qx.ui.form.Button("No");
  win.add(yesBtn);
  win.add(noBtn);

  root.add(win, {left:20, top:top});
  win.open();

  win.addListener("appear", onAppear);
}

addWindow(this.getRoot(), "First Window with a long caption", 20);
addWindow(this.getRoot(), "Second Window", 120);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the minimum width of the window (`win.setMinWidth(150)`, or you can add a spacer after the buttons (`win.add(new qx.ui.core.Spacer(80));`)

See this playground example: https://qooxdoo.org/qxl.playground/#%7B%22code%22%3A%22var%2520win%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.window.Window(%2522First%2520Window%2522)%253B%250A%250Awin.setLayout(new%2520qx.ui.layout.HBox())%253B%250Awin.setShowMinimize(false)%253B%250A%250Avar%2520yesBtn%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.form.Button(%2522Yes%2522)%253B%250Avar%2520noBtn%2520%253D%2520new%2520qx.ui.form.Button(%2522No%2522)%253B%250Awin.add(yesBtn)%253B%250Awin.add(noBtn)%253B%250A%250Athis.getRoot().add(win%252C%2520%257Bleft%253A20%252C%2520top%253A20%257D)%253B%250Awin.open()%253B%250A%250Alet%2520option%2520%253D%25201%253B%250Aswitch(option)%250A%257B%250A%2520%2520case%25201%2520%253A%2520%2520%252F%252F%2520This%2520is%2520likely%2520your%2520better%2520option%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520win.setMinWidth(150)%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520break%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%250A%2520%2520case%25202%253A%2520%2520%2520%252F%252F%2520but%2520this%2520works%2520too.%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520win.add(new%2520qx.ui.core.Spacer(80))%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520break%253B%250A%257D%250A%250A%22%2C%20%22mode%22%3A%22ria%22%7D

Comment: Thank you, Derrell. These suggestions are acceptable but only if we know what approximate size of window. The caption I read from app configuration and this varies ( caption may be short or very long) . Only way I found not using caption and instead of it use qx.ui.basic.Label in window.

Comment: Btw links from qooxdoo playground after some time don't work could I replace it by source code? I've noticed it in some qooxdoo questions.

Answer (score 0):

If a caption can have dynamic size for example is read from configuration files. The way is not use caption for these purposes and use label in window.

```
var win = new qx.ui.window.Window("First Window");
win.setLayout(new qx.ui.layout.VBox());
win.setShowMinimize(false);

var questionLabel = new qx.ui.basic.Label("Do you wanna sleep?");
win.add(questionLabel);

var container = new qx.ui.container.Composite(new qx.ui.layout.HBox());
var yesBtn = new qx.ui.form.Button("Yes");
var noBtn = new qx.ui.form.Button("No");
container.add(yesBtn);
container.add(noBtn);
win.add(container);

this.getRoot().add(win, {left:20, top:20});
win.open();
```